# How to fix this in android studio. its giving me this error inside this..':app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'

Tags: android

When i run my Project on Android. i got this error.

```
/home/ruatfela/AndroidStudioProjects/MizoFood/app/build/intermediates/instant_run_split_apk_resources/debug/instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug/out/slice_1/resources_ap
```

How can i fix it? Im using Linux OS, and my project includes Sqlite and Firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused might be because of  "instant run" feature in studio 2.3, you can disable it by:

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run. Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.

Comment: its working.. thankyou.. so is there any disadvantages in unchecking the box..while working on android in future

Comment: no there is no any disadvantage for this. Its option is for if you want to instant change after modify UI in xml.